# Azure function invoke method from a class library?

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

I'm definetely new to Azure and want to know what would be the best solution/practice to my requirement.

I have a class library project that consists of all business logic for our project.

Now, I have a requirement were I need a job that will trigger/invoke a method from that class library.

We are creating a timer based Azure function that will invoke the method.

Solutions that we are thinking are:

1. Reference the class library project to the Azure function project.
2. Deploy the class library somewhere in Azure (App service or something..) and have the Azure function invoke the method(if this is even possible)

Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Create azure function using visual studio
2. Add your class library reference
3. Deploy your function on azure.

That's all. It should work perfectly.

Comment: I am trying to call other method inside Run method of Function's Run method (to list data). How do I place the method from other class? I have posted this today (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69919689/azure-function-rest-api-for-http-trigger-using-timer-trigger-with-azure-data).