# Azure Function (REST API for Http Trigger & using Timer Trigger with Azure Data Factory)

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to develop an Azure Function and came across a question regards to the requirement for using HTTP Trigger.

I am trying to pull data using a third party's SDK, and it is XML-based web services (XML API), not REST API, so it appears that I cannot use HTTP Trigger.

**1) My understanding is, in order to use HTTP Trigger, I need to have REST API, correct? How about XML API?**

I am trying to go with Timer Trigger and use Azure Data Factory to pull data.

**2) If I use Timer Trigger and Azure Data Factory (ADF), where does data get stored in between?**

Is data stored in the storage account (Table or Blob) that I configured when I created Function App, and then when I execute ADF, data would be pulled from there?

And if so, how does data in the storage account gets truncated (for next run) after it is used?

**3) I am trying to locate where the logic of pulling data should go within the Function CS file.**

I guess I have to call a method from other cs file (ListVendors.cs) inside the Function app solution to list vendors' data, correct?

And the Main class is in another cs (Program.cs) file.

Do I call/put the class name (& method) inside the Function class inside Run method (as shown below)?

**Function class (TimerTrigger_1109_1)**

[image]

**ListVendors class**

[image]

**Main method (Program.cs)**

[image]

I am trying to understand how Function app gets called vs. how Main method is called within Function application.

**4) When I run the solution, how does solution know which file to run (Function file or Main method within the solution)?**
Since this is Function solution, I am not sure how execution of solution works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [JaliyaUdagedara](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/88823/jaliyaudagedara.html) for answering to this thread - [Azure Function (REST API for Http Trigger & using Timer Trigger with Azure Data Factory) - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/622760/azure-function-rest-api-for-http-trigger-amp-using.html)

> So, if I use Timer Trigger and have a logic to pull list of data, how do I move the data to ADF?

As far as I know, ADF cannot directly use  `Timer trigger function`.

But you can create  [schedule triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger)  in Azure Data Factory first:

[image]

Then create a new  `Http Trigger Function`, and write the logic originally written in  `Time Trigger Function`  in  `Time Trigger Function`. Then use the Http trigger function in ADF.

For how to use azure function in ADF, you can refer to this  [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-functions-now-supported-as-a-step-in-azure-data-factory-pipelines/).

[image]